# jsonlite::read_json produces error when requiring data

Tags: r, web-scraping, jsonlite

I used to be able to get data from this page, but now I get an error running the code. Is there another way to read the table?

Table:

[image]

```
library(jsonlite)

data <- jsonlite::read_json('https://api.nasdaq.com/api/ipo/calendar?date=2021-01')

View(data$data$priced$rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message you get might help!

On rdrr.io your reprex gives:
`In open.connection(con, "rb") : URL 'https://api.nasdaq.com/api/ipo/calendar?date=2021-01': status was 'Couldn't resolve host name' Execution halted`
But I can open the link in a browser. On my r.studio server I get a 60second timeout.  Is there API documentation?

https://dataondemand.nasdaq.com/docs/index.html suggests you should be authenticating though?

Comment: there should be a bypass method as we are able to access on the browser? It used to work with that one line of code but now I only get a forbidden error.